# Why NavigableSet JavaDoc states about implementation details?

Tags: java, collections, interface, set

Why is **NavigableSet** [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html) stating about performance metrics if it's only an Interface?

If, in theory, the interface doesn't know details about its implementations, how can the NavigableSet interface describe:

> "The performance of ascending operations and views is likely to be faster than that of descending ones."

There is a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50738555/why-are-concurrentskiplistset-ascending-iterators-faster-than-descending-ones) but a **ConcurrentSkipListSet** is an implementing class.

Comment: Why do you care? Does the answer help you in *any* way, if I may ask?

Comment: I was thinking about implementing this interface but after reading its JavaDoc I found that describes something about performance, 
should I implement it to meet that description or I can do my new implementation in a free way?

Comment: Just do it in your way. If both operations are equally fast, then that's great. If descending is slower, you should probably mention that in the java doc of your implementation

Comment: The goto impl for a navigable set is a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) (which java's TreeSet uses), which has good performance in only one traversal direction.

Comment: @Bohemian TreeSet uses a red-black tree. (It's PriorityQueue that uses a heap.)

Answer (score 3):

There's no "real" way to enforce such behavior in Java, so the documentation is used to describe the expected behavior of the interface from a performance perspective.

This is important for two aspects.

First, as a user of this interface (or any class that implements it), you should be aware of this performance consideration, and write your code accordingly. E.g., in the paragrpah you quoted, it's noted that "The performance of ascending operations and views is likely to be faster than that of descending ones". This means that if you want to iterate over a `NavigableSet`, you should probably iterate from start to end and not the other way round (even though both will work!).

Second, as an implementor of this interface, you should be aware that this is the expectation, and that users of the interface have probably written their code to take this behavior in to consideration (as explained in the previous paragraph). This means, e.g., that you **could** implement a `NavigatableSet` where the performance of a descending operation is better that the performance of its ascending counterpart, but you probably **shouldn't** - this just isn't how users will expect this class to work.